# Script - DriveApp.getFilesByName - get latest version?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As title suggests

Got a script that's fetching a CSV from a specific G-Drive folder, which is currently filtering by a specific file name.

Is it possible to just say 'get the latest file' from that folder instead of searching by the specific name?

Asking because multiple copies of the same file will be uploaded into the same folder (file name is content.csv, copies will either replace that file, or no doubt be uploaded as content(1).csv etc). So, therefore, assumed just trying to 'get the latest file' would be the best way?

Script:

```
  function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // folder where files are saved
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("content.csv").next(); // currently searching by file name
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); csvData.splice(299,csvData.length-300);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the files by date so you can list the recently uploaded files, and when you hit an already downloaded file you just stop whole process.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#orderBy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getLatest(){
  var optionalArgs = {
    orderBy:"modifiedDate",
    q:"title='TITLE'"
  };
  var files = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs).items;
  Logger.log(files);
}
```

This will use the Advanced Services API to search for the files and order them by date. To use this code you'll need to [enable Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), which allows you to use the APIs directly. You should also look at the [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) to know what properties are available. Lastly, `files` holds an array of the files returned by the list.